# Change date format 08 / 03 / 2017 to 08 March 2017

Tags: date, strtotime

I'm trying to change date format from 08/03/2017
08 day
03 Month
2017 year
I I'm using

```
date("d F Y", strtotime($date));
```

the problem is that I Get 03 August 2017 instead of 08 March 2017

PS : I can't use any other then

dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some researchs I found a solution

```
str_replace(' / ', '-',$date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "08/03/2017");
    echo $date->format('d F Y');
```

You can check it to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
You got August because you provide wrong format to this function. Function accept  m/d/y and you provide d/m/y. you can try with this format m/d/y 
or
you can try this with DateTime object.
*/
$date = "08/03/2017";
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
echo $dateObject->format('d M Y');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the input, the solution was str_reolace / by -